# Java exception (Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare())) - what does it mean?

Tags: java, android, exception, runtime-error

in my project i received error:

```
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076): Read: Error
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:793)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.SensorsActivity.<init>(SensorsActivity.java:29)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.SPN_API.invoke_command(SPN_API.java:208)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.SPN_engine.doInvokeCommand(SPN_engine.java:164)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.SPN_engine.processPoUART(SPN_engine.java:127)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.PoUARTSupport.checkPacket(PoUARTSupport.java:65)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at stas.tcp.client.Receiver.run(Receiver.java:46)
02-20 23:32:45.433: E/Receiver(19076):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and i don't know what does it mean for me. I have few threads in my project, and i don't know which made error. When i commented out one and only thred in SensorsActivity.class - error still occured.

--EDIT---

```
public class SensorsActivity extends Activity implements EventListener, StepCounterListener, LinearAccListener, StepDetectorListener, LightSensorListener, PressureSensorListener, GravitySensorListener, RotationVectorListener, RelativeHumidityListener, ProximitySensorListener, TempSensorListener, AccelerometerSensorListener, GyroSensorListener, MagSensorListener {

    public static final long axisssx = 0;
    private TextView lightText, pressureText, signText, noiseText, humidityText, linearAccText, proximityText, tempText, accelText, gyroText, magText, rotationText, gravityText, stepDetectorText, stepCounterText;
    private LightSensor mLightSensor;
    private PressureSensor mPressureSensor;
    private RelativeHumiditySensor mRelativeHumidity;
    private ProximitySensor mProximitySensor;
    private TemperatureSensor mTempSensor;
    private AccelerometerSensor mAccelSensor;    
    private GyroscopeSensor mGyroSensor;
    private MagnetometerSensor mMagSensor;
    private RotationSensor mRotSensor;
    private GravitySensor mGravitySensor;
    private StepCounterSensor mStepCounter;
    private StepDetectorSensor mStepDetector;
    private LinearAccelerometer mLinearAcc;
    private NoiseLevel mNoise;
    public double amp;
    private Handler handler1;

   public long accelx, accely, accelz;

    private SPN_native spnNative;
    private SPN_API spnApi;
    private int argsImageLength;
    private int actualNrOfArgs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.sensors);

        lightText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rLight);
        pressureText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rPressure);
        humidityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rHumidity);
        proximityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rProximity);
        tempText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rTemp);
        accelText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rAccel);
        gyroText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rGyro);
        magText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rMag);
        rotationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rRotation);
        gravityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rGravity);
        stepCounterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSCounter);
        stepDetectorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSDetector);
        linearAccText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rLinearAcc);
        signText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSignMotion);
        noiseText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rNoise);

      //SOUND LEVEL CODE:
        mNoise = new NoiseLevel();

        try {
            mNoise.starter();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sound sensor initiated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        handler1 = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        //this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ 
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Get the volume from 0 to 255 in 'int'
                            //double volume = 10 * mNoise.getTheAmplitude() / 32768;
                            double volume = mNoise.getTheAmplitude();
                            int volumeToSend = (int) volume;
                            noiseText.setText("Volume: " + String.valueOf(volumeToSend));

                            handler1.postDelayed(this, 250); // amount of delay between every cycle of volume level detection + sending the data  out
                        }
                    });
                }
             };

        handler1.postDelayed(r, 250);


        mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());
        mLightSensor.setListener(this);
        Log.e("Sensor Activity:" , "LIGHT SENSOR LISTENER ACTIVE");

        mPressureSensor = new PressureSensor(getBaseContext());
        mPressureSensor.setListener(this);
        Log.e("Sensor Activity:" , "PRESSURE SENSOR LISTENER ACTIVE");

        mRelativeHumidity = new RelativeHumiditySensor(getBaseContext());
        mRelativeHumidity.setListener(this);

        mProximitySensor = new ProximitySensor(getBaseContext());
        mProximitySensor.setListener(this);
        Log.e("Sensor Activity:" , "PROXIMITY SENSOR LISTENER ACTIVE");

        mTempSensor = new TemperatureSensor(getBaseContext());
        mTempSensor.setListener((TempSensorListener) this);

        mAccelSensor = new AccelerometerSensor(getBaseContext());
        mAccelSensor.setListener(this);

        mGyroSensor = new GyroscopeSensor(getBaseContext());
        mGyroSensor.setListener(this);

        mMagSensor = new MagnetometerSensor(getBaseContext());
        mMagSensor.setListener(this);

        mRotSensor = new RotationSensor(getBaseContext());
        mRotSensor.setListener(this);

        mGravitySensor = new GravitySensor(getBaseContext());
        mGravitySensor.setListener(this);

        mStepCounter = new StepCounterSensor(getBaseContext());
        mStepCounter.setListener(this);

        mStepDetector = new StepDetectorSensor(getBaseContext());
        mStepDetector.setListener(this);

        mLinearAcc = new LinearAccelerometer(getBaseContext());
        mLinearAcc.setListener(this);

        spnNative = new SPN_native();
        spnApi = new SPN_API();
    }


    public void onLightSensorChanged(int lux){

        lightText.setText("LIGHT level: " + lux + " lx");
    }

    public void onPressureSensorChanged(long pressure){
        pressureText.setText("\nPRESSURE: " + pressure + " mPa ");
    }

    public void onRelativeHumidityChanged(String humidity) {
        humidityText.setText("\nRELATIVE HUMIDITY: " + humidity);
    }

    public void onProximitySensorChanged(int proximity) {
        proximityText.setText("\nPROXIMITY: " + proximity);
    }

    public void onTempSensorChanged(String temperature) {
        tempText.setText("\nAMBIENT TEMPERATURE :" + temperature + " celcius degree");
    }

    public void onAccelSensorChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {
        accelText.setText("\nACCELEROMETER: \nX: " + axisX + "nm/s^2 || Y: " + axisY + "nm/s^2 || Z: " + axisZ +"nm/s^2");
    }

    public void onGyroSensorChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {
        gyroText.setText("\nGYROSCOPE: \nX: " + axisX + "nrad/s || Y: " + axisY + "nrad/s || Z: " + axisZ + "nrad/s");
    }

    public void onMagSensorChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {
        magText.setText("\nMAGNETOMETER: \nX: " + axisX + " piko Tesla || Y: " + axisY + " piko Tesla || Z: " + axisZ + " piko Tesla");
    }

    public void onRotationVectorChanged(long rot1, long rot2, long rot3) {
        rotationText.setText("\nROTATION VECTOR: \nYaw: " + rot1 + " nrad || Pitch: " + rot2 + " nrad || Roll: " + rot3 + " nrad");
    }

    public void onGravitySensorChanged(long gravity1, long gravity2, long gravity3) {
        gravityText.setText("\nGRAVITY: \nX: " + gravity1 + "nm/s^2 || Y: " + gravity2 + "nm/s^2 || Z: " + gravity3 + "nm/s^2");
    }

    public void onStepCounterChanged(int step) {
        stepCounterText.setText("\nSTEP CONTER: " + step + " steps");
    }

    public void onStepDetectorChanged(String step) {
        stepDetectorText.setText("\nSTEP DETECTOR: " + step);
    }

    public void onLinearAccChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {


        linearAccText.setText("\nLINEAR ACCELERATION: \nX: " + axisX + "nm/s^2 || Y: " + axisY + "nm/s^2 || Z: " + axisZ + "nm/s^2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onStart();
     // Sound based code
//        try {
//          mNoise = new NoiseLevel();
//            mNoise.starter();
//            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sound sensor initiated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
//            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "On resume, sound sensor messed up...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        if(!mLightSensor.register()){
            lightText.setText("\nLight sensor not supported!");       
            //   Toast.makeText(this, "Light sensor not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!mPressureSensor.register()){
            pressureText.setText("\nPressure sensor not supported!");
        }
        if(!mRelativeHumidity.register()){
            humidityText.setText("\nRelative humidity sensor not supported!");
        }
        if(!mProximitySensor.register()){
            proximityText.setText("\nProximity sensor not supported!");
        }
        if(!mTempSensor.register()){
            tempText.setText("\nAmbient temperature sensor not supported!");
        }
        if(!mAccelSensor.register()){
            accelText.setText("\nAccelerometer sensor not supported!");         
        }
        if(!mGyroSensor.register()){
            gyroText.setText("\nGyroscope sensor not supported!");          
        }
        if(!mMagSensor.register()){
            magText.setText("\nMagnetometer sensor not supported!");            
        }
        if(!mRotSensor.register()){
            rotationText.setText("\nRotation Vector sensor not supported!");            
        }
        if(!mGravitySensor.register()){
            gravityText.setText("\nGravity sensor not supported!");         
        }
        if(!mStepCounter.register()){
            stepCounterText.setText("\nStep counter sensor not supported!");            
        }
        if(!mStepDetector.register()){
            stepDetectorText.setText("\nStep detector sensor not supported!");          
        }
        if(!mLinearAcc.register()) {
            linearAccText.setText("\nLinear accelerometer not supported!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void start() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        mNoise.starter();
    }

    private void stop() {
       // mNoise.stop();
    }

    private void sleep() {
       // mNoise.stop();
    }

    private static byte[] longToByteArray(long data, int arrayLength) {
        byte[] array = new byte[arrayLength];
        int n = 0;
        for(int i = arrayLength - 1; 0 <= i; --i) {
            array[n] = (byte)(data >> i*8);
            n++;
        }
        Log.e("SensorActivity", "longToByteArray array= " + Arrays.toString(array));
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: show `SensorsActivity` class code

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ...` should be moved in a handler outside `run()` and possibly need to change to `Toast.makeText(SensorsActivity.this, ...`

Comment: I'm doing it wrong.. because issue still occurs when i change 'getBaseContext()' to "SensorsActivity.this". And when i moved toast outside of run() eclipse show a lot of code errors.. can you give me example how should it be?

Comment: Can you help me with this problem?